# Can Red-Gate generate XML files?

Tags: xml, generator, redgate

Does anyone know if you are able to generate XML files via Red-gate SQL Data Generator 3? Ideally via XSD Schema or from an existing XML file where you can just use Regex commands to format each node in the XML?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question better asked of Red-Gate? It's their product, and they offer tech support to the product users.

Comment: Yes you are correct - but that would mean creating another new forum account etc.. thought this would be easier...

Comment: Except this isn't Red-Gate feature support. :-)

Comment: but it could be :) - assuming you dont know if this is possible...

Comment: No, it is **not** Red-Gate support. This site is supposed to be the place of *last resort*, after you've exhausted other resources. Vendor support for their products is always the first choice.